# add restrict to a postal code with special caracters

Tags: javascript, php

I want to add a restrict to a 'postal code' inside a form for my clients , to allow them to create just accepted code like "58552" or " 58552" with always '58' in the first and with space and also without space

> so the accepted code is :

"58xxx" and " 58xxx"

can any one tell me how to do it with php and java script please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checks to be placed :

- Check if it is 5 or 6 characters long.
- If it is 5 characters long, it should have only numbers
- If it is 6 characters long, it should have only one space in the beginning and rest only numbers
- The first two characters should be "13"

OR

Convert it to number and check like this : `12999 < number < 14000`

Please try to write a code keeping this in mind.
Let us know what all you attempted in your question.

Anyone - If I have missed anything here, please add.